# Upload image using Django built in forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload an image using the Django built in forms, and can't seem to get the image to actually be stored. The form functions as expected, where I can browse for a file, and submit the form (everything else from form is posted and saved), but the image does not get saved into the "media/images" folder

What am I missing here?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    customerTag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    deviceSerial= models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank = True)
    #also tried: image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank = True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from . import models
from .models import CustomUser
from .forms import addNewEquipmentForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class addEquipment(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = addNewEquipmentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'add_equipment.html'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class addNewEquipmentForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'customerTag', 'deviceSerial','image', )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home),
    path('login/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),#django powered login page
    path('newequipment/',views.addEquipment.as_view(), name='newEquipment'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files")
```

**form - Generated by Django:** Sorry about the formatting, I am quite the novice in HTML...

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
  initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/
  bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98
  /SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">PolySense Solutions</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    </ul>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" \="" 
    data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria- 
    expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
    target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria- 
    expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data- 
    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    admin
 </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/login/password_change/">Change 
password</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/login/logout/">
Log out</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
<br>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" 
value="Yi8mpT2rqDGs8ncI05ePMoi4QECBQLPZ3JTKGRbZi1z0VP5nyWPIo7jZvxurx9tA">
<div id="div_id_username" class="form-group"> <label for="id_username" 
class="col-form-label  requiredField">
Username<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div 
class=""> <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus="" 
class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_username"> 
<small id="hint_id_username" class="form-text text-muted">Required. 150 
characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small> </div> 
</div> <div id="div_id_email" class="form-group"> <label for="id_email" 
class="col-form-label ">
            Email address
        </label> <div class=""> <input type="email" name="email" 
 maxlength="254" class="emailinput form-control" id="id_email"> </div> 
</div> 
<div id="div_id_customerTag" class="form-group"> <label 
for="id_customerTag" 
class="col-form-label  requiredField">
            CustomerTag<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div 
class=""> <input type="text" name="customerTag" maxlength="50" 
class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_customerTag"> 
</div> </div> <div id="div_id_deviceSerial" class="form-group"> <label 
for="id_deviceSerial" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
            DeviceSerial<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div 
class=""> <input type="text" name="deviceSerial" maxlength="50" 
class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_deviceSerial"> 
</div> </div> <div id="div_id_equipment" class="form-group"> <label 
for="id_equipment" class="col-form-label  requiredField">

</select> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_image" class="form-group"> <label 
for="id_image" class="col-form-label ">
            Image
        </label> <div class=""> <input type="file" name="image" 
accept="image/*" class="clearablefileinput" id="id_image"> </div> </div> 
<div id="div_id_password1" class="form-group"> <label for="id_password1" 
class="col-form-label  requiredField">
            Password<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div 
class=""> <input type="password" name="password1" 
class="textinput textInput 
form-control" required="" id="id_password1"> <small id="hint_id_password1" 
class="form-text text-muted"><ul><li>Your password can't be too similar to 
your other personal information.</li><li>Your 
password must contain at least 
8 characters.</li><li>Your password can't be a commonly used password. 
</li> 
<li>Your password can't be entirely numeric.</li></ul></small> </div> 
</div> 
<div id="div_id_password2" class="form-group"> <label for="id_password2" 
class="col-form-label  requiredField">
            Password confirmation<span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
</label> <div class=""> <input type="password" name="password2" 
class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_password2"> 
<small id="hint_id_password2" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the same 
password as before, for verification.</small> </div> </div>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**template used to generate form:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<title>Create New Equipment</title>

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Then where it get saved?

Comment: I can't find where it get's saved, it doesn't seem to save anywhere.

Comment: the form shows the "add image" button, and after I browse for the image, then select it, the name of the image is then displayed beside the button on the form. So it appears to be working correctly up to this point. But when I hit "save" to submit the form, the image is not saved anywhere...

Comment: @MattG Please show also the html for your form.

Comment: I added the HTML, sorry for the poor formatting, I am very new to HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one required attribute in form tag. By setting your opening form tag to `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` your image should be saved.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any idea how I change this so that Django makes this change? As this form is automatically generated from Django.

Comment: @MattG You are using crispy filter to render form fields. You properly wrapped these fields with form tags, you just have to add enctype to the opening form tag. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `views.py` I changed this:

```py
form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
```

to this:

```py
form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

and it worked perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).